# Which apps are placing icons on statusbar?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-note-3, customization, 7.1-nougat

I have LineageOS with Android 7.1.2. I reinstalled at once everything I used to have. Now I have 3 icons on statusbar reporting battery charge.

I'm unable to figure out who is placing them. Is there any way that informs which app is placing icons on statusbar? If I could edit it, much better.

Comment: are they on the left? then swipe down and long press the notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Notification History](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) displays a list of all notifications originating from apps and you can compare the app​ icon to that in your status bar to track down the app. You can even see the time stamp of each notification app to help you. As you can see from the pic , it shows notifications from `System UI` also ; that may help you identify the culprit for your battery charging icons

[image]

Once you track the app, you can try revoke it's permissions to show up in status bar. If these icons don't show up in safe mode, it is app based and of they do perhaps you are better off searching for a solution in your device / ROM forums

Comment: Thanks. So, these left icons are notifications? And what are the right ones?

Comment: Indeed left side icons are related to notifications and I just need to acknowledge them. What about right side icons, is there a way to edit what appear there?

Comment: Ok I'm gonna try there. I'm using RessurrectionRemix on Note3. It wasn't hard to root, vanilla SuperSU did the trick.