# M Symbol in the notification area

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

[image]

Did anyone help me to how to disable this M symbol from my notification area. I tried restarting my phone but it again came after some time. I have lenovo k5 vibe note.

Comment: What phone do you have? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: Nope I never installed that macrodriod app.

Comment: See if my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/177724/131553) helps . Also typo in earlier suggestion - check for all apps starting with **M**

Comment: Are you using a Messenger application in "Secure Zone"? Some research shows this usually occures when running applications in secure zone

Comment: Which app has that M notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the main goal is to remove this notification icon. This is most likely caused by **[Secure Zone](http://www.dignited.com/19939/lenovo-k3-note-secure-zone-feature-lets-you-run-2-simultaneous-accounts-of-any-app/)**

> Secure Zone creates an alternate user account which you can run
> simultaneously with your ‘Open Zone’ (Regular account).

One feature of secure zone is cross-zone notifications:

> Cross-zone notifications: Notifications from Secure Zone are displayed
> in Open Zone with a small red dot to differentiate between the two.

**Resolution**

To get rid of such notifications, you have to delete secure zone:

- Switch to secure zone, pull down the status bar, press and hold "secure zone" icon, enter secure zone settings screen.
- Press menu key, and you can see a "delete secure zone" menu.

  [image]

Hope this helps

Credits: [Lenovo K920 Vibe z2 pro Secure Zone](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/K-and-Vibe-Z-Series-Smartphones/Lenovo-K920-Vibe-z2-pro-Secure-Zone/td-p/1811217)

Comment: Which app has that M notification?